# my prinln method is not outputing the same output i want

Tags: java, printing, output

```
int[] array = myLib.loadArray( args[0] );
        myLib.printArray( "original array from file:  ", array, array.length )
```

above is the print order for this statement

```
public int[] loadArray( String fileName ) throws Exception
    {
        
        Scanner infileHandle = new Scanner( new File(fileName) );
        int[] array = new int[1]; 
        int count = 0;
        while ( infileHandle.hasNextInt() )
        {   if (count >= array.length)
                array = upSizeArray( array );
            array[count++] = infileHandle.nextInt();
        }
        return trimArray( array, count );
        
    }
```

and this is the print array method

```
public void printArray( String label, int[] array, int count)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
        //Scanner in = new Scanner(label);
        for( int i=0 ; i<count ;++i )
        System.out.print(array[i] + " " );
        System.out.println();
        
    }
```

it outputs correctly but does not print the between quotation part

```
"original array from file:"
```

just the stuff after it

plz help
this is the array:

```
34 38 55 81 40 48 66 82 13 21 19 32 96 33 52 91 94 6 76 36 80 75 77 8 83 57 98 87 86 63
```

Comment: can you add what is args you are passing to application?

Comment: Can you post data for at least two lines from Lab #10 file?

Comment: like the array?

Comment: Also, one VERY IMPORTANT thing.  I'm guessing you are using a text editor and not an IDE.  A suggestion is to download Visual Studio Code and install the Java extension.  Then you can set break points and step through the code during runtime.

Comment: yes, the array in the file you are reading

Comment: this is the array: 34 38 55 81 40 48 66 82 13 21 19 32 96 33 52 91 94 6 76 36 80 75 77 8 83 57 98 87 86 63
and thank u for the tip

Comment: Can you post in the question please?  If that is two lines, I can't see the line break.  Thanks.

Comment: Without the IDE, you will need to add print statements before your loop and within the loop to see where it's stopping and not building the array.  Put something like this before the while.  System.out.println("while");  This after the while.  System.out.println("in while");  etc

Comment: it prints the array, it just doesn't print the part between the quotation, "original array from file:" this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the string label as parameter. However, you are not using it or printing it in your `printArray` method. You have to include the "label" as well in `System.out.print()` statement so that it gets printed.

```
// out of loop since you want to print the label only once
System.out.print(label);

// loop over array to print each element  
for(int i=0;i<count;++i) {
 System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Cool. Btw if it works as expected, you can mark the answer as "Accepted answer" and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

String label is being passed as a parameter to the function as the string with argument value `"original array from file:"` .  However, you are not printing the label variable (aka label parameter).

```
public void printArray( String label, int[] array, int count)
    {
        System.out.print(label);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
        //Scanner in = new Scanner(label);
        for( int i=0 ; i<count ;++i )
          System.out.print(array[i] + " " );
        System.out.println();
        
    }
```

Think of an argument as the data or information moving from the function call to the function.  Think of the parameter as the variable which stores that argument (or value) when the function executes during runtime.

Comment: do u know why it is printing the between quotation before every number instead of printing it like this: `original array from file:  34 38 55 81 40 48 66 82 13 21 19 32 96 33 52 91 94  6 76 36 80 75 77  8 83 57 98 87 86 63 `

Comment: Put the label print statement before the for loop.  The for loop repeats for each value of i.